# Load Balance Multiple ISP connection

Tags: load-balancer, failover

I am planning to setup a home network with multiple GBPS connections. Currently have 2x GBPS connections which have their own independent router and network. What I am planning to do is buying a 'Mikrotik hEX' which can provide Load Balancing/Failover for the two connections.

The current setup looks as follows:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/3FnYU.png

Also to eliminate the PON devices, will use a single switch with SFP ports. Switch VLANs will bridge ISP connection to the Routers WAN interfaces. The WAN connections will be load balanced and exposed as a single connection on to the LAN interface, which will be connected to another VLAN on the switch. As shown in the diagram below.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/hQolU.png

> Note: The diagram shows 4 WANs which I am planning for future upgrade once the need arises. For that I will be buying a more capable router with enough horse power. For now I will be sticking with 2 connections.

I have two questions:

1. Is the plan going to work in the first place? I have only done setup for basic home networks before this. I have come up with this design after a lot of reading but that is it. I have zero practical experience with more complex networks.
2. Will Mikrotik hEX and Mikrotik CRS112-8G-4S-IN suffice for this? I know I will be limited by line speed of 1Gbps, which should be fine. I am mainly looking Auto Failover/Load Balancing to reduce network downtime with close to 1 Gbps links on LANs.

Any other inputs to improve upon this are welcome.

Comment: Why do you want to connect the ISPs via VLAN and Switch to the hEX, instead of connecting them directly? Is this required by the way you run your physical connections? (And I don't have personal experience with the hEX, so I cannot comment on it).

Comment: Fiber :) . I can't find affordable load balancing router with more than 2 SFP slots. So want some thing that translates the Fiber to CAT6. Right now I have 2 PON devices so that will be cut down to single switch(if this is possible that is)

Comment: Ok, I see. In that case you can probably have distinct bridges (or port groups, or whatever the UI calls them) to translate from one fiber to one CAT6, with no need for a VLAN tag.